# Ejabberd (v2.1.13) ODBC timeout

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

eJabberd Version 2.1.13

We set up an ejabberd server as part of our app about a year ago (Oct 2013).  Shortly after going live we found issues with ejabberd messages locking up when we reached about 1,200 people online (not all of them were necessarily sending messages).

Following much head scratching the issue was traced to a known (unresolved) bug here: https://support.process-one.net/browse/EJAB-1583

In short, an ODBC timeout of 5secs causes a total messaging downtime of 150 seconds ... this rules out the easy fix of extending the timeout because a 7 sec timeout turns into 210 second downtime etc.

I've tried a lot of "experts" to try to find a solution, but it became apparent quite quickly that there are not many experts around.  I'm wondering if anyone has encountered this problem and found a fix, or found ways of reducing the occurances.

The obvious answer is "upgrade", but this is a non-trivial exercise, and our key developer was poached about a year ago (we no longer have the internal expertise necessary).

In summary the questions are:

1. Are there any recommended configuration settings we can use to reduce this issue?
2. Does anyone know a genuine ejabbered expert they could refer us to?

Many thanks,
David

Comment: Some additional information, we seem to be hitting problems at around 400-450 concurrent ejabberd users (vs the 10,000+ it should be able to handle)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to solve the issue with ODBC, especially not trough any settings that would refer to this.  What you might need is custom patch, or actual code upgrade.

Always thought that [process-one](http://www.process-one.net/en/) offers some services regarding ejabberd.  Especially since it is theirs product.

I could also recommend [Erlang Solutions](https://www.erlang-solutions.com/) which offers consulting, both in ejabberd and MongooseIM (their custom fork of ejabberd focused on performance).

And if you looking for someone full time postin offer at [Erlang Central](https://erlangcentral.org/jobs/) might be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I tried Erlang Solutions, but they have an absolutely appalling attitude towards new clients

Comment: :/ sorry to hear that.  Never considered myself beautiful, but still appalling sound little harsh ;) Still hope you will find some wright help.

Comment: Haha. Well if you do any freelance work let me know!